# CAML Designer through ADFS authentication

Tags: caml, adfs, caml-designer

I cannot seem to authenticate via CAML Designer for a SharePoint 2013 on premise installation that is using ADFS and Windows auth for authentication.  In my case, all Windows Users have a deny access policy on the web application level.  Given that CAML Designer can connect to SharePoint Online, I can only assume it supports ADFS.  Is there a way for me to force CAML Designer to use ADFS authentication?

Comment: Do you have Current Credentials ticked or are you supplying the proper adfs credentials by selecting Web Services?